# Can we link an order automatically to a customer's account if they happen to checkout as a guest in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know we can do this manually through the customer's report page.

But, if a past customer purchases a new product as a guest can Woocommerce link that newly purchased product to their account based on their email address automatically?  If so how can we achieve this?

It would be a huge time saver if Woocommerce links any new orders to a customer email if they already have an account.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with this following code

```
/get the user email from the order
$order_email = $order->billing_email;
 
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $order_email);    

// if the UID is null, then it's a guest checkout
if( $user == false){
  
  // random password with 12 chars
  $random_password = wp_generate_password();
  
  // create new user with email as username & newly created pw
  $user_id = wp_create_user( $order->billing_first_name, $random_password, $order_email );
  
  //WC guest customer identification
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'guest', 'yes' );

  //user's billing data
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->billing_address_1 );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->billing_address_2 );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $order->billing_city );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $order->billing_company );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $order->billing_country );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $order->billing_email );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->billing_first_name );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $order->billing_last_name );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->billing_phone );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->billing_postcode );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $order->billing_state );

  // user's shipping data
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $order->shipping_address_1 );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $order->shipping_address_2 );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', $order->shipping_city );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_company', $order->shipping_company );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_country', $order->shipping_country );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $order->shipping_first_name );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $order->shipping_last_name );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_method', $order->shipping_method );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $order->shipping_postcode );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_state', $order->shipping_state );
  
  // link past orders to this newly created customer
  wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user_id );
}
else{
    wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user->ID );
}
```